# any shorthand in C# for multidimensional collection iteration?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

**This may be a silly question, but I do still occasionally discover unexpected tricks**

I frequently deal with two- and three-dimensional arrays. I often need to iterate over all elements using indexing, so I end up writing the same nested loop structure over and over.

```
for (int i = 0; i < set.GetLength(0); i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < set.GetLength(1); j++) 
    {
         for (int k = 0; k < set.GetLength(2); k++) 
         {
             set[i, j, k].DoSomething();
         }
    }
}
```

I often need my (i j k) iterators, so I'm not looking for a `forEach`.

I just wondered if there might be a way to achieve something very similar with fewer keystrokes?

Thanks a million

Comment: You could create a matrix of the index values for each dimension using a `Tuple<int,int,int> ` (or Tuple of n where n = number of dimensions) and then `foreach` over the list of tuples.

Comment: Now there's a thought!  Seems to satisfy the sugary / keystrokes request.  Not sure what I was expecting, but that's clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the idea of making a matrix of the indices, you could make a set of Extension Methods for each number of array dimensions you need to work with, that way the nested loops are removed from your program logic.

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetIndices<T>(this T[,] set)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < set.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < set.GetLength(1); j++)
                yield return new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>> GetIndices<T>(this T[,,] set)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < set.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < set.GetLength(1); j++)
                for (var k = 0; k < set.GetLength(2); k++)
                    yield return new Tuple<int, int, int>(i, j, k);
    }

    public static void ForEach<T>(this T[,] set, Action<Tuple<int, int>, T> loopBody)
    {
        foreach (var indices in GetIndices(set))
            loopBody(indices, set[indices.Item1, indices.Item2]);
    }

    public static void ForEach<T>(this T[,,] set, Action<Tuple<int, int, int>, T> loopBody)
    {
        foreach (var indices in GetIndices(set))
            loopBody(indices, set[indices.Item1, indices.Item2, indices.Item3]);
    }
}
```

**Sample Usage**:

```
set.ForEach((indices, value) => Console.WriteLine("Value at [{indices.Item1}, {indices.Item2}, {indices.Item3}] = {value}");
```

Comment: I love this idea.  It's similar to something I do already (with tuple-like structs) but I never built extensions.  Definitely gonna try this out.  Much obliged,